# .htaccess - Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to change the URL for a website but I can't figure it out.
The normal URL is:

```
example.com/grades.php?CRSE_ID=12345&GRADE_DT=2014-05-23&VAKNAAM=ADS-blok-1_2&RESULTAAT=Satisfied
```

And I want to rewrite it to:

```
example.com/grades/12345/2014-05-22/ADS-blok-1_2/Satisfied
```

However when I tried this I'm getting a lot of errors such as:

```
Unexpected token <   collapse.js
Resource interpreted as Script but transfered with MIME type text/html: "example.com/grades/12345/2014-05-22/ADS-blok-1_2/assets/js/collapse.js".
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "example.com/grades/12345/2014-05-22/ADS-blok-1_2/assets/img/image.png".
```

The .htacces which I tried to use is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^grades/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /grades.php?CRSE_ID=$1&GRADE_DT=$2&VAKNAAM=$3&RESULTAAT=$4 [L]
```

I guess the error is in my .htaccess file, because it checks for images inside the /grades/12345/2014-05-22/ADS-blok-1_2/ folder, but the js files and images are in the root (where the .htaccess file is located).

Answer (score 0):

This is not to do with your .htaccess

The error messages are because you are serving your javascript in a script environment, whilst using the mime type "text/html" (the mime type for js files is "application/javascript")

The second error is more confusing, but indicates the browser is trying to load the javascript as an image, whilst it is being serves as html; there are two obvious problems here- but without seeing the page which is calling the javascript, it is impossible to tell you exactly what is going on here!

Comment: Oops! I typed the second error wrong. It can't find an image, I will edit it right now. I also can't give the URL because it's behind a password of my own account (cant change the password). I can open up teamviewer so you can check it out. Do you think you can help me?